# regular expressions for file types - jQuery uploader issue

Tags: php, jquery, regex

I'm trying to implement the [jQuery uploader](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) into a webpage.  All the files are in the right places, and we're using the standard regular expression that comes with the software (`/.+$/i`), which I believe should accept all files.

But when you try and upload a file, it quits straight away and gives `Error: filetype not allowed`.  The filename I'm trying to upload is `1234.jpg`.

Anyone any ideas?  I've tried Googling it, but not come across the same problem with this specific uploader.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Regexp that you gave (/.+$/i) fits for the '1234.jpg' string. the problem should be in something else.

Comment: Is there a page online that we can play with? That regex seems legit to me, it means: `.+` any character, 1 or more times `$` end of string and the `i` modifier makes it case insensitive which is redundant but not harmful

Comment: @rtpHarry: The page I'm working on is on a development server at the moment and isn't connected to the net.  But its a straight forward install of the ZIP download from the above github website, if anyone can/wants to take a look!

Comment: I haven't looked at the package yet but you are using a supported browser/version right?

Comment: @rtpHarry: Ah! You could have hit on something there - i'd assumed the latest version of Safari on Mac 10.7 would be fine ... however, just tried Firefox 7.0.1 and it works with that! But i think the only thing that shouldn't work with Safari is the drag-and-drop, which i've not tested yet!  Puzzelling!

Comment: @rtpHarry: Ah, no forget that! It works with a 96KB file, but not with a 900KB file!  Now coming up 'Internal Server Error' ... also strangely, when it change the folder away from the default 'files' folder to 'uploads', Firefox comes back with the same 'Filetype not allowed error!'

Comment: What is the setting of `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in `php.ini`?

Answer (score 0):

If the file is zero bytes then it won't upload.